# Using df.apply() to a time column that indicates times at every 2 seconds in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am new to this data science world and trying to understand some basic pandas examples.
I have a pandas data frame that I would like to create a new column and add some conditional values as below:
It will include `yes` at every 2 seconds. Otherwise include `no`. Here is an example:
This is my original data frame.

```
    id  name    time
0   1   name1   260.123
1   2   name2   261.323
2   3   name3   261.342
3   4   name4   261.567
4   5   name5   262.123
...
```

The new data frame will be like this:

```
    id  name    time     time_delta
0   1   name1   260.123  yes
1   2   name2   261.323  no
2   3   name3   261.342  no
3   4   name4   261.567  no
4   5   name5   262.123  yes
5   6   name6   262.345  yes
6   7   name7   264.876  yes
7   8   name8   265.234  no
8   9   name9   266.234  yes
9   10  name10  267.234  no
...
```

The code that I was using is:
`df['time_delta'] = df['time'].apply(apply_test)`
And the actual code of the function:

```
def apply_test(num):
    prev = num
    if round(num) != prev + 2:
        prev = prev
        return "no"
    else:
        prev = num
        return "yes"
```

Please note that the time column has decimals and no patterns.

The result came as all `no` since the prev is assigned to the next number at each iteration. This was the way I thought it would be. Not sure if there are any other better ways. I would appreciate any help.

UPDATE:

- Please note that the time column has decimals and the decimal values have no value in this case. For instance, time=234.xxx will be considered as 234 seconds. Therefore, the next 2 second point is 236.
- The data frame has multiple second value if we round it down. In this case, all of them have to be marked as `yes`. Please refer to the updates result data frame as an example.

Comment: You could do that by making `prev` a global.  You can see that, as you have it, `prev` is always going to equal `num`.  You'd have to figure out where to initialize it.

Comment: If you had `262.234` right after `262.123` should it also be a yes or should it be no? Conversely, if the `262.123` row was missing, should `263.345` be yes?

Comment: so, the time values has to be in order logically, but in this dataset, it can come as non-order. Also, we can ignore the decimal points. Sorry, I should have declared in the actual post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check when the remaining of the cumulative sum of the `diff` changes value after divided by 2, that is when it enters a new segment of length 2:

```
remaining = (df['time'].diff().cumsum() // 2).fillna(0)
df['time_delta'] = np.where((~remaining.duplicated()), 'yes', 'no')
```

Comment: More efficient than `diff`+`cumsum`+`fillna`, you can use `df['time'].sub(df['time'].iloc[0])`. Nice one otherwise, +1

Comment: Appreciated the feedback. `sub` indeed does a better job here.

Comment: Great answer! This provides `yes` to only single value. I have multiple 264.xxx seconds. In this case, only one of them gets yes. How do we extend this to return  all of them as yes?

Comment: What makes `264` to be `yes` and `263.xxx` to be `no` in this case? Could you update your question with a more detailed explanation?

Comment: Just updated the question. not sure if the update answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
import numpy as np

N = 2 # time step

# define bins every N seconds
bins = np.arange(np.floor(df['time'].min()), df['time'].max()+N, 2)
# get the index of the first row per group
idx = df.groupby(pd.cut(df['time'], bins))['time'].idxmin()

# assign "yes" to the first else "no"
df['timedelta'] = np.where(df.index.isin(idx), 'yes', 'no')
```

Output:

```
   id   name     time time_delta
0   1  name1  260.123        yes
1   2  name2  260.323         no
2   3  name3  261.342         no
3   4  name4  261.567         no
4   5  name5  262.123        yes
5   6  name6  263.345         no
6   7  name7  264.876        yes
```